# get data from two tables fetching only one row from second table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

i have two tables

t1:

```
sno  val
12   A
13   B
14   C
```

t2:

```
refid   val2
13      ba
13      bb
13      bc
```

using the following query:

```
select * from t1,t2 where t1.sno=t2.refid order by t2.refid;
```

and the query

```
select * from t1 join t2 on t2.refid = ( select refid from t2 where t1.sno = t2.refid limit 1 )
```

I get

```
B ba
B bb
B bc
    and so on for all the possible combinations.
```

I want to get only first combination instead of all three like

```
B ba
C ca
    and so on...
```

I mean, I just want only first row for every three combination that I am getting as a result of join.

Comment: This will be harder in MySql. The best solution uses a lateral join (APPLY operation in Sql Server). All of the other major databases have supported this for at least 5 years now, but along with CTEs, FULL JOIN, windowing functions, and much more, it's just one of those things the current MySql release won't do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one value and one column from the second table, a correlated subquery is an easy solution:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.val2
        from t2
        where t1.sno = t2.refid
        order by ?  -- whatever defines "first"
        limit 1
       ) as val2
from t1
order by t1.sno;
```

If you only want rows where there is a match, MySQL has a nice extension for `having` that fits the bill:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.val2
        from t2
        where t1.sno = t2.refid
        order by ?-- whatever defines "first"
        limit 1 
       ) as val2
from t1
having val2 is not null
order by t1.sno;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, I suggest below two ways to get your required output:

Way1 : 
Use nested query to group by records then do join

`select * from t1 a join (select * from t2 group by refid) b on a.sno= b.refid`

way2:
But it's better to add auto increment key for tables like t2. Once you added auto increment key that will be useful in most use cases.

First add auto increment key to your table t2 by using below command

`ALTER TABLE t2 add column id int(11) key auto_increment first;`

Then execute the below join query:

`select * from t1 a join (select *from t2 where t2.id in(select min(id) from t2 group by refid)) b on a.sno= b.refid`

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.val,temp.refid from t1,(select t2.refid as refid, min(t2.val2) as val2 /*Assuming "first" row criteria*/ from t2 group by t2.refid) temp where t1.sno=temp.refid order by t2.sno;
```

Eliminated duplicates from t2 using sub-query and joined with t1.

Answer (score -1):

select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sno ORDER BY val2 ) AS rn, * from [dbo].[t1] a
join [dbo].[t2] b on a.sno = b.refid
) t
where rn  = 1

Comment: This only works for sql server. The question is tagged MySql.